# roblox Lua- Checkpoint system leaderboard does not refresh

Tags: lua, roblox

I have made a checkpoint system that respawns the player in the place of the checkpoint and a leaderboard should display the checkpoint the player is on. here is the script I'm using:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local checkpoint = script.Parent -- the checkpoint that will update the leaderboard

function onTouched(hit) -- when the checkpoint is touched by something
    if hit and hit.Parent and hit.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid") then -- if the hit object is a player's character
        local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) -- get the player from the hit object
        local checkpointData = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("CheckpointData") -- get the folder that stores the checkpoint data
        if not checkpointData then -- if the folder does not exist
            checkpointData = Instance.new("Folder") -- create a new folder
            checkpointData.Name = "CheckpointData" -- name it CheckpointData
            checkpointData.Parent = ServerStorage -- parent it to ServerStorage
        end

        local userIdString = tostring(player.UserId) -- get the user id of the player as a string
        local checkpointValue = checkpointData:FindFirstChild(userIdString) -- get the value that stores the checkpoint of the player
        if not checkpointValue then -- if the value does not exist
            checkpointValue = Instance.new("ObjectValue") -- create a new value
            checkpointValue.Name = userIdString -- name it with the user id of the player
            checkpointValue.Parent = checkpointData -- parent it to the CheckpointData folder

            player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character) -- when the player's character spawns
                wait() -- wait for one frame
                local storedCheckpoint = ServerStorage.CheckpointData[userIdString].Value -- get the stored checkpoint of the player
                character:MoveTo(storedCheckpoint.Position + Vector3.new(math.random(-4, 4), 4, math.random(-4, 4))) -- move the character to the stored checkpoint with some random offset
            end)
        end

        checkpointValue.Value = checkpoint -- update the value with the current checkpoint

        local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") -- get the leaderstats object of the player
        if not leaderstats then -- if the leaderstats object does not exist
            leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder") -- create a new folder
            leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats" -- name it leaderstats
            leaderstats.Parent = player -- parent it to the player
        end

        local checkpointStat = leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Checkpoint") -- get the stat that displays the checkpoint of the player
        if not checkpointStat then -- if the stat does not exist
            checkpointStat = Instance.new("IntValue") -- create a new int value
            checkpointStat.Name = "Checkpoint" -- name it Checkpoint
            checkpointStat.Parent = leaderstats -- parent it to the leaderstats folder
        end

        checkpointStat.Value = tonumber(checkpoint.Name) -- update the stat with the name of the current checkpoint as a number

    end
end

checkpoint.Touched:Connect(onTouched) -- connect the function to the event
```

The checkpoints do respawn the player but the leaderboard starts at 0 when the player touches the first checkpoint and the leaderboard does not refresh after stepping on another checkpoint